# rows csv into nested list

Tags: python, csv, nlp

I'm a beginner in programming, but for a natural language processing project I need to work with csv. 
I have this csv file with annotated text. The sentences are separated from each other with an empty row. Each row is a token (word or punctuation with it's annotation). What I need is a nested list like this `[[[I,pronoun],[need, verb], [you, pronoun]], [[Do, verb], [you, pronoun], [need, verb], [me, pronoun]]]`

The text looks like this in the csv:

```
I  pronoun
need  verb
you  pronoun

Do  pronoun
you  pronoun
need verb
me  pronoun
```

I tried the following code, but then I only get one big list and not a nested list. I don't know how to split the sentences into different lists on the empty row.

```
 sentences = []
    for row in text:
        sentences.append(list(row))
 print(sentences)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
sentences = []
with open('my_file.csv', 'r') as R:
  curr = [] # store current sentence
  for row in R:
    if len(row) == 0:
      # empty line
      sentences.append(curr) # add current sentence to pool
      curr = [] # start a new sentence
      continue
    curr.append(row.strip().split()) # assuming no leading 1. etc.
```

I am using [`strip`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) to remove empty spaces from the beginning/end of the line, and [`split`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) to split a string (`row`) into list elements.

Comment: I understand your code, thank you for that. But I get the error message 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' at the last line of code. Which I find weird, because you split rows and not the list curr

Comment: @Bambi what is your `row`? it seems like your `text` is not a text file handle, but something else (`csv` reader?)... If your `row` is already a list `[<word>, <part-of-speech>]` then you can simply `curr.append(row)` and the code should work fine for you.

Comment: yes indeed. I forgot to mention that. I use a csv reader. Now it works perfectly, big thanks!